# Displaying an image together with the search results in jQuery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, autocomplete

so I'm working on this project which requires in the integration of jQuery autocomplete. The search displays the products that are in the database (it's a type of ecommerce websie).
But, the requirement is, that a small image should be displayed as well (right or left) of each search result.
I've read about this and got to know that **renderitem** does the magic, but due to my little knowledge in jQuery, I'm unable to make it.

Here's my code for jQuery.

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
      source: "search.php",
      minLength: 2,
      select: function( event, ui ) {


        log( ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.label :
          "Nothing selected, input was " + this.actor );
         window.location.href = './products/' + ui.item.productid;
```

**search.php**

```
<?php
include 'dbconnector.php';

// Sanitise GET var
if(isset($_GET['term']))
{
$term = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['term']);
// Add WHERE clause
//$term="Apple";
$query = "SELECT `productid`, `productname` FROM `products` WHERE `productname` LIKE '%".$term."%' ORDER BY `productid`";


$result = mysql_query($query,$db) or die (mysql_error($db));
$id=0;
$return=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    //array_push($return,array('label'=>$row['productid'],'actor'=>$row['productname']));
    //array_push($return,array('value'=>$row['productid'],'label'=>$row['productname']));
    //array_push($return,array('actor'=>$row['productname'],'label'=>$row['productid']));
    array_push($return,array('productid'=>$row['productid'],'label'=>$row['productname']));

}

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($return);
//var_dump($return);

exit(); // AJAX call, we don't want anything carrying on here
}
else
{
    header('Location:index');
}

?>
```

**Database structure**
*Products table*

```
Index ID     Product ID   ProductName    Price
```

*productimages table*

```
productid  imagepath
```

The images exist on the server in a /productimages/ folder.
Ant suggestions for this would be helpful.

Comment: I'm still in need of some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas that may help you.

Check out this link found in the documentation https://github.com/scottgonzalez/jquery-ui-extensions/blob/master/src/autocomplete/jquery.ui.autocomplete.html.js
Not sure if that will work.

A way to work in what you need. This should work (though I did not test it but it's not specific code but rather a principle).
Try to proceed as follows:

From your search.php also return the path to the images in such a way that you can identify which image belongs to which tag, a tag being the returned string (guessing productname). 
Now when your JS gets this data build a data-structure to hold this information and one only holding the tags. Or just fill two arrays so that tags[i] corresponds to images[i].
Use the array of tags to initialize your autocomplete.

Now we do the magic. As stated in the documentation you can extend _renderItem( ul, item ). http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#method-_renderItem

```
_renderItem: function( ul, item ) {
    return $( "<li>" )
    .attr( "data-value", item.value )
    .append( $( "<a>" ).text( item.label ) )
    .appendTo( ul );
}
```

Now here you have  item.label. This should be one of the tags you safed away earlier when you got the data from search.php. Find the corresponding image to this tag.
add append an image with the link you just found as source.

```
.append( $( "<img>" ).src( /* the link you found */ )
```

adding this after the line appending the link should add the image inside your a-tag. Now you only need to use some css to style it all.

Have a link at the first link to see how to code an extension for jQuery that replaces the mothode with your new one.